There is no option to click the button in header only on some pages
I have tried to solve this problem on my own but nothing works for me.
1 scn - On the main page https://customqualitymanufacturing.ca/ when hovering over the Products button in the header everything works fine and I can click on all three subcategories: "Products" "Distributor Ordering" "Warranty", and the same happens on other pages like https://customqualitymanufacturing.ca/BLOG/.
2 scn - On the page https://customqualitymanufacturing.ca/product-category/MERCHANDISE/ and on the page https://customqualitymanufacturing.ca/WARRANTY/ I am not able to click on the subcategory "Distributor Ordering" on the Products button in the header.
Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?
I am using WordPress.com as well as Woocommerce.
I'm really looking forward to the response from the community and would appreciate any time everyone spends. I am in touch every minute.



You appear to have no less than 12 copies of that dropdown menu in your source code. I'd suggest trying to get rid of 11 of them first, with any luck one of them will be the one that's malfunctioning. If not, it'll make for easier troubleshooting.

Thanks for trying to help!
Do you happen to know where I can find copies of this drop-down menu in WordPress?

It looks to be generated by Elementor.
